# Example tasks of a data scientist and the necessary knowledge

Tags: knowledge-base

Could you give some examples of typical tasks that a data scientist does in his daily job, and the must-know minimum for each of the levels (like junior, senior, etc. if there are any)? If possible, something like a [Programmer competency matrix](http://www.starling-software.com/employment/programmer-competency-matrix.html).

Comment: This is an example of a career question. Please join in on the [discussion here](http://meta.datascience.stackexchange.com/q/41/62) and voice your opinion if you feel this should be on-topic.

Comment: There is no easy answer to this question, IMO.  Workloads and project goals vary significantly.  Think of immunology, for example.  An immunologist's tasks will vary throughout his career and at the senior level the focus will be very specialized.  Data science is like that, but even more broad because the technologies they work with and the data they work with can vary so much.  A data scientist at Facebook is going to have a very different workload and type of data to analyze than one at Baxter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Becoming a Data Scientist – Curriculum via Metromap](http://nirvacana.com/thoughts/becoming-a-data-scientist/) is a popular reference for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

The [Programmer Competency Matrix](http://sijinjoseph.com/programmer-competency-matrix/) is just a set of skills, which are more likely to occur when being a real programmer than other skills, they are not a checklist to being a programmer, or for that matter, required to be a programmer; most common way to know someone is a programmer is that they're paid to be a programmer, which honestly has nothing to do with programming skills.

To be a data scientist, do data science.